# How could scroll HorizontalListView automatically

Tags: android

Such as `ListView`, it invokes `smoothScrollToPosition(index)`
`Android Developer Doc` doesn't have `HorizontalListView`. I downloaded this custom `HorizontalListView` from `GitHub`, but I'm confused about how to use `HorizontalListView` on scrolling automatically.

could recyclerview scroll loop, and it scroll in specified time

Comment: What is the library name?

Comment: it's the same to this link https://github.com/kk-java/HorizontalListView/tree/master/HorizontalListView

Comment: please check this demo, simple and best example ::::http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Comment: did you try with view pager

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using recyclerview with a linear layout manager that is set in horizontal mode

Comment: I want to use recyclerview, but according to the app structure and the deadline, I don't have enough time, do you have some other solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you need only a HorizontalListView RecycleView is the way to go.

Just add this line of code to convert it to a HorizontalListView

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Refrence can be found here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use recycle view and set layout manager as follows

```
listView= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.hlistview);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
        listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

See this  [example on github](https://github.com/vkdinventor/MyRecycleView)